# Host File under MacOSX

Tags: dns, hosts

I am trying to edit my host file to see how it works. But with no success.
I enter this in my `/etc/host` file:

```
173.194.66.103 www.youtube.com
```

And when I type `173.194.66.103` on the browser I get redirected to Google (which it is!) instead of YouTube. Anything I am missing out?

Did try this one too but with no success `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Answer (score 1):

Hostnames are intended to abstract the user from IP addresses. You've got the abstraction backwards.

You can see this quite clearly with a tool like `ping`:

```
anew@Wintermute:~$ ping google.ca
PING google.ca (74.125.226.24): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.226.24: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=11.224 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.226.24: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=18.605 ms
^C
--- google.ca ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.224/14.915/18.605/3.690 ms
```

Now if I add

```
127.0.0.1 google.ca
```

to my `/etc/hosts` file, when I execute ping I see:

```
anew@Wintermute:~$ ping google.ca
PING google.ca (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
^C
--- google.ca ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.051/0.077/0.104/0.026 ms
```